# bitcoin allowip not working

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin.conf

My bitcoin.conf file has the following lines:

```
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=192.168.*.*
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Error: Invalid -rpcallowip subnet specification: 192.168.*. Valid are a single IP (e.g. 1.2.3.4), a network/netmask (e.g.
>   1.2.3.4/255.255.255.0) or a network/CIDR (e.g. 1.2.3.4/24).

How do I allow an IP range as I did before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That format has been removed.

Use

```
rpcallowip=192.168.0.0/16
```

instead.